# What is the difference between Delphi library routines IsUNCRooted and IsUNCPath?

Tags: windows, delphi, filepath, unc

The current documentation of both functions reads very similar to each another:

- [System.IOUtils.TPath.IsUNCRooted](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.IsUNCRooted)
- [System.IOUtils.TPath.IsUNCPath](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.IsUNCPath)

Both are static members of the same class, with one of them decorated `inline`, so I wouldn't think they are separate implementations with equivalent functionality you often find across various Delphi classes (although examples within a common class do exist in Embarcadero's standard library).

Specifically, I can't come up with a case where a path is a valid UNC path but not a *rooted* UNC path. So what does `IsUNCRooted` even mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IsUNCRooted` only checks if the parameter starts with an UNC sequence, while `IsUNCPath` also checks the rest for valid path names. So a valid UNCPath is indeed also UNC rooted, but not always the other way round.